# How to optimize upload to avoid file overwrite in FilePond JS?

Tags: javascript, php, upload, filepond

I am currently using FilePond JS to upload files to a server environment. However, when I upload a file with the same name, it overwrites the previous upload. Therefore, I implemented a new move_file function that I plugged in submit.php inside the handle_transfer_ids_post($ids) function.

**Note:** I need to retrieve the filename for future use.

**New move_file function:**

```
function final_move_file($file, $path) {
  require(__DIR__."/../../App/Setup.php");
  initSession();

  $name = $file['name'];
  $name = pathinfo($name);
  $file['name'] = $_SESSION['user_id']."_".$name['filename']."_".date('Y-m-d_h-i-s').".".$name['extension'];
  array_push($_SESSION['uploads'], $file['name']);

  if (is_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'])) {
    return move_temp_file($file, $path);
  }

  return rename($file['tmp_name'], $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . sanitize_filename($file['name']));
}
```

I am not quite sure to understand the original move_file function and I think this can be simplified.

Cheers

Comment: if your code it's working the way you want. you just should look in the docs to understand better.

Comment: I did look at the documentation, it does not mention anything regarding inner class functions.

Comment: The FilePond project doesn't have an opinion of where and how you store files. Some store files in the db others in folders, it's up to the dev to choose how to make each file unique.